# Using Eloquent to order lists in Laravel cannot give the expected result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In the Controller of my Laravel project, I want to get two lists in different orders with `Product` Model, so I wrote code below:

```
$products = Product::where('status', 0);
$newProduct = $products->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
$hotProduct = $products->orderBy('click_counts', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
```

I found that `$newProduct` gets the correct sort but not the `$hotProduct`. Unless I change the code like this:

```
$newProduct = Product::where('status', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
$hotProduct = Product::where('status', 0)->orderBy('click_counts', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
```

My question is why my first code snippet wrong and can't give the expected result?

Comment: You are continuing the first query. That is the problem. You need to start query from scratch for hotProduct.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze Thanks for your reply. So I can not define a retrieving model for more than one query, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to re-define the whole query or alternatively you can clone a query so that you have two completely independant queries, otherwise, if you are using the first version which gives you wrong result, hotProducts query will take old query object (which was already modified on your second line) and continue from adding query parameters from there. So your second query under the hood will have all the constraints for $newProduct + additionally constrains to $hotProduct and will give a wrong result.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze Thanks for your time to explain my confusion, I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
$newProduct = Product::where('status', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
$hotProduct = Product::where('status', 0)->orderBy('click_counts', 'desc')->limit(15)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this works but I just want to know why the first query is wrong.

Comment: without `->get()` values are not get from table@Runbing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$products = Product::where('status', 0);
$newProduct = $products->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(15);
$hotProduct = $products->orderBy('click_counts', 'desc')->limit(15);

return view('foo.bar', ['newProduct', $newProduct->get(), 'hotProduct' => $hotProduct->get()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives same result as my first code snippet.